# mod_rewrite to replace all dots with underscores after path

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, redirect, mod-proxy

I've been through all tagged questions here and on SO, but my problem is different because of either/both needing to replace "`.`" with "`_`" comes after a particular path and I'm running through a `proxypass`.

I am trying to change:

http://somedomainname.com/grafana/dashboard/db/generic-ping?var-device=SF-some.machinename.com

to:

http://somedomainname.com/grafana/dashboard/db/generic-ping?var-device=SF-some_machinename_com

Code:

> Options +FollowSymLinks
>
> RewriteEngine On
>
> ProxyPreserveHost On
>
> ProxyPass /grafana http://100.65.7.97:3000
>
> ProxyPassReverse /grafana http://100.65.7.97:3000

I've tried many things after hours of scouring serverfault/stackoverflow/webmasters.stackexchange/google etc. But nothing I try is successfully redirecting. I'm not sure why.

Some of the things I've tried (and variations on them):

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]*)\ (.*)$ $1_$2 [E=%E2:yes,N]
RewriteCond %{ENV:%E2} yes
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
```

...

```
RewriteRule       ^(/?grafana/dashboard/db/.*/[^/]*?).([^/]*?.[^/]*)$ $1_$2 [N]
RewriteRule       ^(/?grafana/dashboard/db/.*/[^/]*?).([^/.]*)$       $1_$2 [R=301]
```

...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*).(.*).(.*)/$
RewriteRule (.*).(.*).(.*)/ http://somedomainname.com/grafana/dashboard/db/$1_$2_$3/ [R=301]
```

...and many others...

Could this be an issue because I'm also using `proxypass`? Maybe I'm just overlooking something simple? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var-device=SF-some.machinename.com` is part of the `QUERY_STRING`, not the `REQUEST_URI`. Your last rule looks kinda correct except you need to escape the periods.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^/grafana/dashboard/db/generic-ping /grafana/dashboard/db/generic-ping?%1_%2_%3 [R=301]
```

where `%1` = `var-device=SF-some`, `%2` = `machinename` and `%3` = `com`.

Comment: Works! Great description, thank you for clarifying the `QUERY_STRING` part, and for pointing out the need to escape the periods. This was a learning experience. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: any chance you'd be able to help out with this similar question?: http://serverfault.com/questions/762198/mod-rewrite-with-multiple-query-strings ...your help would be greatly appreciated.